# What is a restartpoint in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-13

In the postgresql.conf file for PostgreSQL version 13, the archive_cleanup_command comment explains the command in the following way:

```
#archive_cleanup_command = ''         # command to execute at every restartpoint.
```

The documentation [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/pgarchivecleanup.html) and [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/continuous-archiving.html) have no mention of a 'restartpoint'. This raises the following questions:

1. **What is a restartpoint?**
   For example: is restartpoint just the same word for a checkpoint? Do the two mean the exact same thing?
2. **When is a restartpoint created?**
   For example: if the restartpoint is just a checkpoint then the check point will be created every 5mins or whatever the setting for checkpoint_timeout is in postgresql.conf file.
3. **When is the archive cleanup command run?**
   For example: The archive cleanup command is run every time the archive_timeout (set in the postgresql.conf file) is reached. If the archive timeout is set to 1hr, then the archive_cleanup_command runs every 1hr.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A restartpoint is just a checkpoint during recovery, and it is triggered in the same fashion as a checkpoint: either by timeout or by the amount of WAL processed since the last restartpoint. [Note also that](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/wal-configuration.html)

> Restartpoints can't be performed more frequently than checkpoints in the master because restartpoints can only be performed at checkpoint records.

The reason for restartpoints is “restartable recovery”: if your recovery process is interrupted, the next restart won't start recovering from the beginning of the backup, but from the latest restartpoint.

`archive_cleanup_command` is run for all completely recovered WAL segments during a restartpoint. Its main use case are log shipping standby servers: using `archive_cleanup_command` they can remove all shipped WAL segments they don't need any more, so that the directory containing them doesn't grow out of bounds.

Comment: How often is an archive cleanup command run? How does postgresql know when to run it?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name provided me with an answer as to how often an archive cleanup command is run....it is triggered by a checkpoint timeout or is run when the wal size is about to exceed max_wal_size.

Comment: I have added more information about how restartpoints are triggered.

Comment: For anyone else in the future that has the same question: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/279742/understanding-the-archive-cleanup-command